# Making windows time uneditable

Tags: windows, time

When the windows time is set with a wrong time and a file is created,the file takes that time as date modified. Later on,when the time is corrected, the file still remains with wrong time and it is hard to understand when the file was modified. To avoid this confusion,how can the time of windows be made not to be editable.

Comment: This question is not appropriate for asking on StackOverflow. Better ask here: [SuperUser](https://superuser.com/).

Answer (score 0):

You can prevent the time from being changed by other users by editing the local security policy. Run `secpol.msc`, navigate to `Local Policies` and to `User Rights Assignments`. On the right, edit the item `Change the system time` and `Change the time zone` (if required) to your liking.